# Same margin both sides, still does not look centered

Tags: css, web

Trying to set a nav bar centered, but imo it looks closer to the left side than to the right.

I am giving it a width and half of the remaining one as left side margin, but does not change. I ser margin of the elements to 0 in case it might affect, and same to the padding. Does anyone have an idea if there is an element with margin i am not counting on? Thanks

```
nav{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 25vw;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: why not just use `margin-left: 50vw` ?

Comment: nothing changes, nav does not move

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. Remove `margin:auto` from the class. CSS always uses the last rule it finds, so if margin is declared twice, it will pick the second one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd recommend using flex box for this purpose. You'll need an inner element like this:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.inner {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="inner">
    Hello world!
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're close to the solution.
First, specify margin *after* margin-XXX, overrides it.
The solution consists of keeping margin-top and add both margin-left and margin-right set to auto.

Note: for the demo, I have set a border to the nav so that one can see it centered; also, I’ve centered the text within the nav for aesthetic reason.

```css
nav{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    /*margin-left: 25vw;*/
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 1px red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
navigation menu
</nav>
```